# how to pass imageurl/database value form view code to html img tag

Tags: asp.net, html, image, code-behind

is there any way i can assigned an imageurl to html img tag from database like ... something like that or i can assign image url to html img tag from code behind like imgCaravan.ImageUrl= "~/images/" + rdr["image"].ToString();

As I am using a image swapping jquery which uses html  tag to display images . The issue is I am getting the image url from the database , i just cant find a way to pass the url to html  tag, I can do this by using asp image control.

Any help or tutorials will be appreciated

thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I unrderstand well you search for the `img10.Attributes["src"]="/photofile.gif"`, to make this running you also need to add the `runat="server" id="img10"` on your `<img` tag.

How ever I suggest to add a literal in the place that you like to display the image, and just make a full render of the img tag.

Eg: `<asp:literal runat="server" id="img10" />` and then just set your image `img10.Text = "<img src="/imgafilename.gif" alt="" />"`

Comment: if i use literal , i cant use jquery swapping gallery coz its function is linked to <img> tag

Comment: @Muhammad Yes you can use - literan did not create any tag, but you can render anything inside.

Comment: just a quick query , can u have a look at my another question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403654/handling-images-from-database-to-jquery-image-swapper