# handling images from database to jquery image swapper

Tags: jquery, asp.net, image, datalist

Is there anyway of handling images from database to jquery image swapper or any other type of image swapper.
the images should be populated depending on the number of images generated from the databse. I can get all the
images from the databse but I cant find a way to show those images on the jquery image swapper. 
I can display all the images by using datalist but with data list i cant use the jquery image swapper.
Any possible solution or alternative will be highly appreciated

```
 protected void showDetails(int makeID)
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Price,image,make from productDetail Where (makeID LIKE @makeID)"  , conn);
    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();

   param.ParameterName = "@makeID";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
  //  cmd.Parameters["@makeID"].Value = makeID;
   param.Value = makeID;

    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
       // Label3.Text = rdr["price"].ToString();

        lblMake.Text = rdr["make"].ToString();
        lblPrice.Text = rdr["Price"].ToString();

        atest2.Attributes["href"] = "~/images/" + rdr["image2"].ToString();

        test2.Attributes["src"] = "~/images/" + rdr["image2"].ToString();
        test2.Attributes["height"] = "75";
        test2.Attributes["width"] = "75";

    }

    conn.Close();

}
```

// on the design view

```
<div id="page">
        <div id="container">

            <h2>Thumbnail rollover effects and slideshow crossfades</h2>

            <!-- Start Advanced Gallery Html Containers -->
            <div id="gallery" class="content">
                <div id="controls" class="controls"></div>
                <div class="slideshow-container">
                    <div id="loading" class="loader"></div>
                    <div id="slideshow" class="slideshow"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="caption" class="caption-container"></div>
            </div>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" name="drop" id="atest2" title="Title #1" runat="server" >
                            <img  id="test2" runat="server" alt="Title #1" />
                        </a>
                        <div class="caption">
                            Any html can be placed here ...
                        </div>
                    </li>
</ul>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is your jQuery for swapping the images?

Comment: http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/index.html   , i am using galleriffic jquery to acheive that , but the jquery uses <img> <li> tags and i cant programmatically increase these tags depending on the number of images, coz the images from the database can be 5 or 10. Hope you understands the scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an asp.net repeater to create the html markup needed.

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="container">

        <h2>Thumbnail rollover effects and slideshow crossfades</h2>

        <!-- Start Advanced Gallery Html Containers -->
        <div id="gallery" class="content">
            <div id="controls" class="controls"></div>
            <div class="slideshow-container">
                <div id="loading" class="loader"></div>
                <div id="slideshow" class="slideshow"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="caption" class="caption-container"></div>
        </div>

<div id="thumbs">
    <ul class="thumbs noscript">
        <asp:Repeater id="rptImages" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <a class="thumb" name="optionalCustomIdentifier" href="path/to/slide" title="your image title">
            <img src='<%#String.Format("/images/{0}", Eval("image"))%>' alt="your image title again for graceful degradation" />
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                    (Any html can go here)
                </div>
            </li>
            ... (repeat for every image in the gallery)
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>        
    </ul>
</div>

 <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just bind your List of images to this repeater and output their paths within the image tagss.

This work for you?

EDIT

For your code behind you would want to do something more like this below, and i have updated the code above to show your output.

```
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
rptImages.DataSource = rdr;
rptImages.DataBind();
```

Comment: let me try it , will let u know in a bit :)

Comment: ny examples of using repeater neva used b4

Comment: how will i pass the href and img src to the design view

Comment: I have just edited the above question for u to see the code which i am running now

Comment: thnx for the help , will it repeat for all the images for a specific product , for instance i have got 5 images for marble product and 6 images for another marble product , i myt have created a wrong database as i have given 6 columns for images , so that user can insert 6 images and if user insert 3 images it fills that row with null.

Comment: how can i pass values like 1.jpg , 1a.jpg,1b.jpg,1c.jpg,1d.jpg  to Eval("image") , for instance if i pass the query string 1 which will return the above images url saved in a database and i have to pass these to Eval("image") in a repeater control so that it can display all the images linked to that particular id (querystring)

Comment: my select query will be like  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from productDetail Where (makeID LIKE @makeID)"  , conn);

Comment: I just figure it out there was a problem with my sql query :Select productDetail.Price, productDetail.make, makeImages.makeImages" +
        "as makeImages from productDetail INNER JOIN makeImages ON productDetail.makeID=makeImages.makeID Where (productDetail.makeID LIKE @makeID)",conn);